# Selenium issues with finding an element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

For some reason the I cant identify the the button element in the below html `button class="next"`. Ive tried various methods but I never get a positive hit. Ive confirmed its not in an iframe and as all the methods i have tried (id, class, xpath("//li[@class='next']/button")) Im hoping someone could point out my stupidity.

```
<div id="ember1199" class="ember-view">
    <ol id="ember1582" class="results-paginator ember-view">
        <!---->    
        <li class="page-list">
            <ol>
                <li class="active">1</li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1585="1585">2</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1587="1587">3</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1589="1589">4</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1591="1591">5</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1593="1593">6</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1595="1595">7</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1597="1597">8</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1599="1599">9</button></li>
                <li><button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1601="1601">10</button></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="next" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1602="1602" data-is-animating-click="true">
                <div class="next-text">
                    Next
                </div>
                <span class="svg-icon-wrap">
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-right-icon" size="small">
                        <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon">
                            <g class="small-icon" style="fill-opacity: 1">
                                <path d="M9,8L5,2.07,6.54,1l4.2,6.15a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,0,1.69L6.54,15,5,13.93Z"></path>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </li-icon>
                </span>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `[@class='next']` be on the button rather than the `li`? `//li/button[@class='next']`

Answer (score 0):

To identify the button element with `class="next"` you can use either of the following :

- **`css_selector`**

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.next span.svg-icon-wrap > span")
  ```
- **`xpath`**

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='next']//span[@class='svg-icon-wrap']/span")
  ```

Comment: hmm I have tried similar methods to no avail, just tried both of your suggestions and I get no element found errors as before.

Comment: Updated my answer, let me know the status

Comment: Same thing, however I just did a `print` of a soup object and it seems the entire top level div is missing and I cant see why

Comment: It seems the page source and whats being seen in selenium is quite different. Is there a way to maybe print the DOM objects?